# Redirect to page after Simple News subscription

Tags: 8, emails

I wish to redirect the user to a specific page once they have inputted their email and pressed subscribe. Does anyone know how to achieve this please?

I have found the setting to achieve this but upon deeper digging it is not working. An issue has been opened here -> https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews/issues/2822420

Comment: Did you check if it works in the latest development version of the module? I feel like I fixed that at some point.

Comment: No sorry I didn't check this, will try that before below suggestions, thanks

Comment: Edit, no this doesn't seem to have fixed it. Tried 8.x-1.x-dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do as follows:

> use Drupal\Core\Url;

```
function MODULENAME_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'FORM_ID') {
    foreach (array_keys($form['actions']) as $action) {
        if ($action != 'preview' && isset($form['actions'][$action]['#type']) && $form['actions'][$action]['#type'] === 'submit') {
          $form['actions'][$action]['#submit'][] = '_redirect_submit';
        }
    }
  }
}
/**
 * Add redirect to user after subscription.
 */
 function _redirect_submit(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    //If you know route name you can do like this
    $form_state->setRedirect(ROUTE_NAME); // example as "user.admin_create" redirects to user create page
    // If you have path do like below.
    $destination = "INTERNAL_URL";
    $url = Url::fromUri('internal:' . $destination);
    $form_state->setRedirectUrl($url);
 }
```

Comment: Never send a response directly, in form submit set it in form_state: `$form_state->setResponse($response);`. Although for a redirect url you don't need to build the response, because you can use `$form_state->setRedirectUrl()`

Comment: @4k4 Edited answer as per your suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please implement hook_form_alter() into your custom module..

```
/*
* Implement hook_form_alter()
*/
function custom_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'user_register_form':
        $form['#submit'][] = 'custom_form_submit';
      break;
  }
}


function custom_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state){             
  return new RedirectResponse(\Drupal::url('user.page'));
}
```

Thank You.

Comment: The general direction is correct, but the code is bogus. There is no `$form['#redirect']`, it needs to be set on $form_state and it must be set in a submit callback

Comment: Then need to set submit handler into hook_form_alter() as form[#submit][] and set the redirection page using drupal_goto() into form_submit(). as i update my answer.

Comment: drupal_goto() has been removed. Kindly check this link https://www.drupal.org/node/2023537

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need! https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect /. 
I made a redirect after subscribing with url mysite.com/node to anothersite.com .